# How to tokenize a string containing null values using strtok_r

Tags: c, string

I have a string which contains some comma separated values. The value may or may not be NULL. like :

```
strcpy(result, "Hello,world,,,wow,");
```

I want null values to be printed accepted too. How can I proceed while using strtok_r which gives me NULL values too.

I tried this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char result[512] = { 0 };
    strcpy(result, "Hello,world,,,wow");
    char *token, *endToken;
    int i = 0;
    token = strtok(result, ",");
    while (i < 5) {
        printf("%d\n", ++i);
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is :

```
1
Hello
2
world
3
wow
4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know why it is giving Segmentation fault. I want the solution so that output is like:

```
1
Hello
2
World
3
*
4
*
5
wow
```

I want `*` to be printed for the null tokens but null tokens are not even extracted.

Comment: Have you read the focumentation of `strtok`?

Comment: use `strsep` instead of `strtok`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - tagged C.  Is `strsep()` part of the C standard?  Think is just GNU C extension.

Comment: What do you mean by "null"?

Comment: @ryyker `strsep` is  not standard C. but `strtok_r` too.

Comment: Presumably by "NULL values", you mean empty string, such as `""`.

Comment: You can use pointer arithmetic and `strlen` on the items to figure out if empty elements where skipped over.

Comment: @FUZxxl : yes I have read the documentation and it says contiguous delimiters are considered as one. I wanted to know what could be the work around this?!

Comment: @adnaan.zohran As the documentation said, it skips empty fields. There isn't anything you can do about that; if there was a trick to not skip empty fields, the documentation would have said so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From strtok_r man page:

> A sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter characters in the parsed  string is  considered  to be a single delimiter.

So it won't work in your case. But you can use code like this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    char result[512];
    char *str = result, *ptr;
    strcpy(result, "Hello,world,,,wow");
    while (1) {
        ptr = strchr(str, ',');
        if (ptr != NULL) {
            *ptr = 0;
        }
        printf("%d\n", ++i);
        printf("%s\n", str);
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        str = ptr + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This works for now!! thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `strsep()` you can roll your own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char result[512] = "Hello,world,,,wow";
    char *token, *endToken;
    int i = 0;

    token = result;
    do {
        endToken = strchr(token, ',');
        if (endToken)
            *endToken = '\0';           // terminate token
        printf("%d\n", ++i);
        if (*token == '\0')             // substitute the empty string
            printf("*\n");
        else
            printf("%s\n", token);
        if (endToken)
            token = endToken + 1;
    } while (endToken);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
1
Hello
2
world
3
*
4
*
5
wow
```

Answer (score 0):

For strtok to find a token, there must be a first character that is not a delimiter. It only returns NULL when it reaches the end of the string, i.e. when it finds the `'\0'` character.

> To determine the beginning and the end of a token, the function first scans from the starting location for the **first character not contained in delimiters (which becomes the beginning of the token)**. And then scans starting from this beginning of the token for the first character contained in delimiters, which becomes the end of the token. The scan also stops if the terminating null character is found.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok