# Parsing file when no data between tokens

Tags: c, parsing, struct, token, delimiter

Hey guys I'm reading in a file and want to parse the data into an array of struct. The file looks something like this:

```
Country,City,Area Code,Population
China,Beijing,,21256972
France,Paris,334,3568253
Italy,Rome,,1235682
```

I want to parse the data and assign members to each respective area in the file. I have no issue parsing the data on lines 1 and 3. But in the case that there is no area code and there are two comma's next to each other the token becomes null and I get an error. I've been searching forever and can't seem to find a solution. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    static struct Locations {
        char country[20];
        char city[20];
        char areaCode[5];
        char population[100];
    } line[2000000];

    // open file
    FILE *Lfile;
    Lfile = fopen("locations.txt", "r");
    if (!Lfile) {
        perror("File Error");
    }

    char buf[100];
    const char delim[2] = ",";
    char *token;

    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buf, 100, Lfile) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(buf, delim);
        while (token != NULL) {
            strcpy(line[i].country, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            strcpy(line[i].city, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            strcpy(line[i].areaCode, token); //Error here
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            strcpy(line[i].population, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n", line[i].country,
               line[i].city, line[i].areaCode, line[i].population);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524489/how-to-tokenize-a-string-containing-null-values-using-strtok-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `strtok()` to split a CSV file because `strtok` considers sequences of characters from the separator string to act as a single separator.  It is only meant to be used to split space separated tokens.

You cannot use `sscanf("%[^,]", ...)` either because `sscanf` expects to parse at least one character different from `,`.

You could use `strchr`, or you can use another function from `<string.h>` for your purpose: `strcspn()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* copy at most len bytes from src to an array size char and
   null terminate it.  Return the length of the resulting C string
   possibly smaller than len if the destination is too small.
*/
size_t strcpymem(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src, size_t len) {
    if (len >= size)
        len = size - 1;
    memcpy(dest, src, len);
    dest[len] = '\0';
    return len;
}

#define RECORD_NUMBER   2000000

int main(void) {
    static struct Locations {
        char country[20];
        char city[20];
        char areaCode[5];
        char population[100];
    } line[RECORD_NUMBER];

    // open file
    FILE *Lfile;
    Lfile = fopen("locations.txt", "r");
    if (!Lfile) {
        perror("File Error");
    }

    char buf[100];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < RECORD_NUMBER && fgets(buf, 100, Lfile) != NULL) {
        char *p = buf;
        int len = strcspn(p, ",\n");
        strcpymem(line[i].country, sizeof line[i].country, p, len);
        p += len;
        if (*p == ',') p++;
        len = strcspn(p, ",\n");
        strcpymem(line[i].city, sizeof line[i].city, p, len);
        p += len;
        if (*p == ',') p++;
        len = strcspn(p, ",\n");
        strcpymem(line[i].areacode, sizeof line[i].areacode, p, len);
        p += len;
        if (*p == ',') p++;
        len = strcspn(p, ",\n");
        strcpymem(line[i].population, sizeof line[i].population, p, len);
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n", line[i].country,
               line[i].city, line[i].areaCode, line[i].population);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` is troublesome to use to scan zero-length fields.
`strtok()` combines adjacent tokens.
Sometimes the best answer is to write some code.

---

Form a helper function to parse the sub-strings.  Some untested code follows.  The key is to divide code's functionality along easier to maintain functions

```
// Starting a `p`, copy until delimiter found or size exhausted
// Return NULL on failure
const char *foo(const char *p, char *dest, size_t size, int end) {
  if (p) {
    while (size-- > 0 && *p) {
      *dest = *p++;
      if (*dest == end) {
        *dest = '\0';
        return p;
      }
      dest++; 
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Re-write main loop

```
// Make buf big enough
char buf[sizeof line[0] * 2];

// Use size_t rather than int
size_t i = 0;
// Limit iteration count
while (i < RECORD_NUMBER && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, Lfile) != NULL) {
  const char *p = buf;
  p = foo(p, line[i].country,    sizeof line[i].country,    ',');
  p = foo(p, line[i].city,       sizeof line[i].city,       ',');
  p = foo(p, line[i].areaCode,   sizeof line[i].areaCode,   ',');
  p = foo(p, line[i].population, sizeof line[i].population, '\n');
  if (p == NULL || *p != '\0') {
    printf("Bad line '%s'\n", buf);
    exit (-1);
  }
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I love to use `sscanf` for these kind of parsing.

```
int i = 0;
while (fgets(buf, 100, Lfile) != NULL) {
    char *pbuf = buf;
    int offset;
    pbuf += sscanf( pbuf, "%[^,],%n", line[i].country , &offset) ? offset : 1;
    pbuf += sscanf( pbuf, "%[^,],%n", line[i].city    , &offset) ? offset : 1;
    pbuf += sscanf( pbuf, "%[^,],%n", line[i].areaCode, &offset) ? offset : 1;
    pbuf += sscanf( pbuf, " %s",       line[i].population );

    printf("%s %s %s %s\n", line[i].country,
           line[i].city, line[i].areaCode, line[i].population);
    i++;
}
```

Maybe this is slower code, maybe it crashes with malformed lines. Maybe it has other flaws, but this is how I like doing this kind of parsing.

**Note:** If parsing blank field, the char pointer will not be set to `NULL`. It is therefore important to initialize the structure.

**EDIT:** Fixed the bug when handling empty fields.

Comment: This code actually fails to read empty fields: you should initialize the destination fields.  It would invoke undefined behavior if the line does not contain enough `,` and if any of the fields are longer than the destination arrays.

Comment: Yes, you are right chqrlie! I worked in my test since it I had initialized the structure, but the initializing code was omitted in the posting. :-o

Comment: If `buf[0] == ','`, this code leads to undefined behavior.  No limit on input length with `"%[^,]"`.  "Fixed the bug when handling empty fields."  --> no, it fails.  Many problems - not testing result of sscanf() before using `line[i].city`, using `offset` without knowing it has been set.

Comment: It is indeed a little more subtile: if the line has missing fields, the last field will be parsed, and the scan will stop because the `,` is missing, `sscanf` returns `1` and `offset` is unchanged, so `pbuf` is not updated properly...  `sscanf` can do quick and dirty parsing, but it is very difficult to make it dependable.

Comment: @chqrlie Disagree about "very difficult to make it dependable".  Yet this code is weak.

Comment: Yes! You are right at all your points. Will `sscanf(buf, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%s", county,city,areaCode, population);` be any better? I can then check id the returned value is 4.

Comment: @chux: from what we see on stackoverflow, the quirks and shortcomings of `scanf` are beyond most programmers skill level for even the simplest parsing tasks. That's what I call *very difficult*.  Even savvy experts get caught regularly by the unintuitive semantics of these functions.  Tell me you never experienced that yourself `;-)`

Comment: @oysteijo: no, this format does not parse empty fields correctly and does not prevent buffer overflows.  Use the code from my answer, that does not use `sscanf`, nor `strtok` and handles all these special cases.

Comment: @chqarlie: Thanks for your comments. Will upvote your answer. And I will stop using `scanf` from now on. However I will not rewrite all my code. :-)

Comment: @oysteijo: Thank you.  You can look at your current implementations and try and determine what input could cause your `scanf`s to fail... it is a very good exercise.  Once you master that, you can probably corner any other programmer on his use of these functions.

Comment: `"%[^,]"` will read nothing into the target if the first character is `','` is a key problem to this approach.